# check if every row in two columns has the same sign

Tags: r, dataframe

Sorry that i didn't specify: V1 and V2 are factor values. When I

`sign(as.numeric(df$V1)) == sign(as.numeric(df$V2))`

Every case returns true.

---

Check if every row in two columns has the same sign.
Return false if one is 0, but true when both are; an example is as follows:

```
V1  V2
-1  2.3
3.6 2
-2  -4
0   4
0   0

V1  V2   comparison
-1  2.3    false
3.6 2      true
-2  -4     true
0   4      false
0   0      true
```

I came up with this which always returns true:

```
output.df$comparison = (((as.numeric(output.df$V1) > 0) & (as.numeric(output.df$V2) > 0)) | ((as.numeric(output.df$V1) < 0) & (as.numeric(output.df$V2) < 0)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare their `sign` which will handle case for 0 as well.

```
df$comparison <- sign(df$V1) == sign(df$V2)
df

#    V1   V2 comparison
#1 -1.0  2.3      FALSE
#2  3.6  2.0       TRUE
#3 -2.0 -4.0       TRUE
#4  0.0  4.0      FALSE
#5  0.0  0.0       TRUE
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(-1, 3.6, -2, 0, 0), V2 = c(2.3, 2, -4, 
4, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: sorry that i didn't specify - V1 and V2 are factor values. When I sign(as.numeric(df$V1)) == sign(as.numeric(df$V2)). Every case returns true.

Comment: @Michelle Run `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` and then try the above answer. Or to run this directly do `df$comparison <- sign(as.numeric(as.character(df$V1))) == sign(as.numeric(as.character(df$V2)))`

Answer (score 1):

Another `base R` idea could be:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) sd(sign(x))) == 0

[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

*dplyr* way:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(comparison = (sign(V1) == sign(V2))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.